# Best practice for mobile applications

Tags: android

I develop a mobile application in which I consume several APIs, create a sqlite database and use many libraries. But my application is not faster.
Is there anyone can help me with a good practice document for the mobile app at the level of performance (speed, storage).

Comment: please read these: [ask] & [mcve] & [help/on-topic]

Comment: Maybe also read this http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920035053.do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the use of so many methods and libraries, Android has created (and I suggest you) the multidex application which is nothing but a so light version of your own application! 
Take a look...
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html